# Rebuild materialized view log

Tags: oracle

I need to drop and re-create a view log only if it references a specific column.  I don't see anything in dba_mview_logs or sys.mlog$ that describes the base columns a view log references.

Comment: You can query the `LOG$_T` table is see what columns it holds. the log table will store only the columns you included in sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT MASTER, LOG_TABLE, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM USER_MVIEW_LOGS
    JOIN USER_TAB_COLS c ON table_name = LOG_TABLE
WHERE MASTER = 'TABLE_WHERE_LOGS_ARE_TAKEN'
```

Comment: Perfect thx. Wasn't aware the log table info was stored in user_tab_cols.